# Probability of the largest number

Tags: probability

An urn contains $10$ balls numbered $1-10$. A set of $3$ balls is drawn from the urn and let $X$ record the largest number showing. Compute Prob($X=8$).

What I have:

$10^3$= the number of different sequences.
The number of balls chosen is $\binom{10}{3}$. So the probability for $X=8$ is $\frac{\binom{10}{3}}{10^3}$.

Comment: Hint: Prob(X=8) = 1 - (probability of having a 9 or 10)

Comment: I think it is intended that drawing is without replacement. There are $\binom{10}{3}$ equally likely choices. There  are $\binom{7}{2}$ ways to get an $8$ and two numbers that are $7$ or less.

Comment: The solution above does not use the value 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the solution you presented

$10^3$ represents the number of ways three balls can be chosen in such a way that each ball is **returned** to the urn **before** you make your next pick.

Whereas $\binom{10}{3}$ represents the number of ways three balls can be chosen in such a way that each ball is **not returned** to the urn before you make your next pick.

You are after the number of sets where **8** is the highest ball =  $\binom{7}{2}$ , divide that by the total number of possible three  ball sets $\binom{10}{3}$ and you have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

How many ways can you draw 3 balls from 1-10 such that 8 is the maximum? Divide it by the total number of ways you can draw 3 balls from 1-10.